# Is there a way to get the binding of the calling scope?

Tags: ruby

I know they this isn't really something that one would do normally, but it's more for debugging than anything else. How would one get the binding of the calling scope?

Comment: `def foo; binding.pry; end; def bar; x = 123; foo; end` -- Inside the binding, you cannot possibly have access to the `x` variable.

Comment: Although there is this gem that **hacks** the functionality in: https://github.com/banister/binding_of_caller